# OrientDB - JavaScript delete function

Tags: orientdb

I wanna delete record using JS API. In wiki I found [example](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/Functions.html#response-object) and I know that exist `delete()` function but I don't know what paramets needed and can't find documentation about ORid realize interface.

**Update**

When I create or insert function I get error

`Internal server error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Script pool for database 'myDataBase' is not configured`

I use this code:

```js
db.save()

//or

db.executeCommand()
```

Need help. Maybe who know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for a graph database

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var vertex=g.getVertex("your rid");
vertex.getRecord().delete();
```

and this for a document database

```
var db=orient.getDatabase();
var document=db.query("select from #21:0");
document[0].delete();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I get error `orient.getGraph is not a function in <eval> at line number 32\nTypeError: orient.getGraph is not a function"`

Comment: Are you working with a graph or a document database ?

Comment: document database

Comment: It is work! But few minutes ago I get error I update my issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127303/discussion-between-alessandro-rota-and--).